# SQL resultset "POST PROCESSING" result into composite keyed like representation for commonly occurring (left) join that ends up with rows repeated

Tags: javascript, java, c#, sql

I can not find any satisfactory answer on this seemingly common issue with rows repeating for join queries.

---

---

Note I am looking for a **very** **particular** answer, but I know this is possible to do.

So I believe in order for this not to get out of hand with answers that go off the trail please, try to adhere to these rules:

1. Do not produce a response in how to do it in pure SQL, or at the DB level.
2. Do not answer with a very specific answer to this exact problem with hard to reuse code. It needs to be repeatable with other structures. It means the joins/nesting can be arbitrarily long, and not limited to two as in this example.
3. You may utilize pseudo code or any language you like as long as it is commented on the process and clear. Personally I utilize Java so would have been ideal.
4. No hibernate solutions.
5. Is as efficient as possible but postprocessing after row/col collection with Java streams might be ok but is not the ideal solution. On the fly grouping would be ideal on the first iteration of the data.

Now, lets dig deeper:

What we have is output that looks something like this:
[image]

Entire create, insert and query can be found here on **dbfiddle**:
https://dbfiddle.uk/a6TIilXz

From the fiddle it is quite easy to understand the relationship of the columns.

We know from this query that the join is :

> account_3.id = accountshop_5.account

Lets call this relationship for **shops**

Then we know another join:

> accountshop_5.shop = shoptext_9.shop

Lets call this relationship for **texts**

So we can define:

```
let relations = {
    'account_3.id -> accountshop_5.account' : 'shops',
    'accountshop_5.shop -> shoptext_9.shop' : 'texts'
}
```

---

---

The goal is to iterate the **eachRow**, and **eachColumnKey** and in the end generate something that will look like this:

```
[
    { /* account_3 */
        
        id: 'account.1',
        
        shops: [ /* accountshop_5 */
        
            {
                id      : 'account.1 ::shop.1',
                account : 'account.1',
                shop    : 'shop.1',
                
                texts: [ /* shoptext_9 */
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.1 :: txt.1',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.1',
                        txt : 'This is txt 1'
                    },
                    
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.1 :: txt.2',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.1',
                        txt : 'This is txt 2'
                    },
                    
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.1 :: txt.3',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.1',
                        txt : 'This is txt 3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            {
                id      : 'account.1 ::shop.2',
                account : 'account.1',
                shop    : 'shop.2',
                
                texts: [ /* shoptext_9 */
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.2 :: txt.7',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.2',
                        txt : 'This is txt 7'
                    },
                    
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.2 :: txt.8',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.2',
                        txt : 'This is txt 8'
                    },
                    
                    {
                        id  : 'shop.2 :: txt.9',
                        
                        shop: 'shop.2',
                        txt : 'This is txt 9'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I believe the problem here is well defined.

I've tried somethings in Java, I tried to collect them row by row, column by column, but was not able to add the finishing touches to the end array.

---

---

**In Java**, I've attempted to use streams after iterating all rows to collect them, then using `groupingBy` but not successfully later been able to build the desired object.

**Here is a fully working** and **compilable** **Java example** that you can play with directly that works on similarly structured data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[]   keys = new String[]{ 
                     "club.id",        /***/ "club.country",  /***/  "fan.id", /***/ "fan.age" };
    String[][] rows = new String[][]{  /***/                  /***/            /***/           
                                       /***/                  /***/            /***/           
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "peter" , /***/ "18",     },  
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "peter" , /***/ "18",     },  
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "peter" , /***/ "18",     },  
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "jonas" , /***/ "19",     },  
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "jonas" , /***/ "19",     },  
        new String[]{ "barca",         /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "jonas" , /***/ "19",     },
                                                                             
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "80",     },  
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "80",     },  
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "80",     },  
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "90",     },  
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "90",     },  
        new String[]{ "real",          /***/ "spain ",        /***/  "sara"  , /***/ "90",     }
          
    };
    
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] row : rows) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    
        int i = 0; for (String key : keys) {
            map.put(key, row[i++]);
        }
        
        list.add(map);
    }

    // System.out.println(Gsons.PUBLICS_PRETTY.toJson(list));
 
    String[] groupsBy = new String[]{ "club.id", "fan.id", "fan.age" }; 
    String[] namesBy  = new String[]{ "clubs"  , "fans"  , "ages"    };

    Object o = list.stream()
        .map(row -> {
            return row;                    
        })
        .collect(
            
            groupingBy(row -> { return row.get(groupsBy[0]); },
                groupingBy(row -> { return row.get(groupsBy[1]); },
                        groupingBy(row -> { return row.get(groupsBy[2]); } 
                    ) 
                ) 
            )
        )
    ;

    // System.out.println(Gsons.PUBLICS_PRETTY.toJson(o));;
}
```

The input in the Java example after having been built up has:

```
[
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "peter",
    "fan.age": "18"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "peter",
    "fan.age": "18"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "peter",
    "fan.age": "18"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "jonas",
    "fan.age": "19"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "jonas",
    "fan.age": "19"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "barca",
    "fan.id": "jonas",
    "fan.age": "19"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "80"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "80"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "80"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "90"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "90"
  },
  {
    "club.country": "spain ",
    "club.id": "real",
    "fan.id": "sara",
    "fan.age": "90"
  }
]
```

But the output I am able to get currently is the following which is not entirely correct:

```
{
  "barca": {
    "jonas": {
      "19": [
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "jonas",
          "fan.age": "19"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "jonas",
          "fan.age": "19"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "jonas",
          "fan.age": "19"
        }
      ]
    },
    "peter": {
      "18": [
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "peter",
          "fan.age": "18"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "peter",
          "fan.age": "18"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "barca",
          "fan.id": "peter",
          "fan.age": "18"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "real": {
    "sara": {
      "90": [
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "90"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "90"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "90"
        }
      ],
      "80": [
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "80"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "80"
        },
        {
          "club.country": "spain ",
          "club.id": "real",
          "fan.id": "sara",
          "fan.age": "80"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The desired output for the Java example would be something like:

```
[
     {
         'clubs' : [
             {
                 'club.id'      : "barca",
                 'club.country' : "spain",
                 'fans' : [
                     {
                         'fan.id'  : "peter", 
                         'ages'    : [
                             {
                                 'fan.age' : 18
                                 // Nothing more to add here, but in theory possible
                             },
                             {
                                 'fan.age' : 19
                                 // Nothing more to add here, but in theory possible
                             }
                         ]
                     },
                 ]
             },
             
             {
                 'club.id' : "real", 
                 'fans' : [
                     {
                         'fan.id'  : "peter", 
                         
                         'ages'    : [
                             {
                                 'fan.age' : 18
                                 // Nothing more to add here, but in theory possible
                             },
                             {
                                 'fan.age' : 19
                                 // Nothing more to add here, but in theory possible
                             }
                         ]
                     }
                 ]
             }
         
         ]
     }
     
]
```

I know it looks long, but it is because I've also provided lots of data to reproduce it so you can play it it.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: The `_5` and `_9` are confusing me, they seem irrelevant, unclear why you would need to alias like that. The ultimate goal is still unclear. So are you trying to take a single table, and nest all its foreign-keyed tables as JSON objects? Why is pure SQL disallowed, it looks like it could be done with dynamic SQL generated from querying the system tables for foreign keys? Do you want an answer in Java, C# or JS? Picking only one will likely get you a better answer.

Comment: What format is your input? You've got 3 different way here,  1)You've shown a database which could be read as input, 2)you've hardcoded an input in code with `new String[]`, 3)and you have a JSON input also. It does look like you want a JSON output though.

Comment: No, I don't want json output. Just that kind of structure. I have to present to you someway. Yes, it comes from the database. Currently a Java ResultSet at its core. But the source of the data is less relevant which is why I had to produce a smaller example which can easily be used to further the cause. You may try it on a ResultSet as well.

Comment: @Charlieface I am not sure how it is confusing but it is confusing to me as well TBH. I haven't been sure how to tackle the problem and surely the _9 does not help. The reason for them is that you might sometimes have joins on the same table, so you want to be able to distinguish them. You may try to look at the other example which does not have these, but try to look past them I would say. SQL agg functions will not do because you are assuming the result is always serializable, which almost anything is, even bytea but it is not ideal to transform it into one col/val at the DB level. Java!

Comment: Well you can use nested `JSON_OBJECT_AGG` functions, and generate those dynamically. Please be clear about what exactly you are trying to achieve, in other words how do you want to make this more generic (more able to deal with different table designs)? Which tables would you automatically include, what happens if you have a recursive foreign-key etc?

Comment: @Charlieface I think you are thinking too far ahead. The problem at hand is to be able to modify the table rows, as in grouping them by their join points. Then presenting them in the fashion I presented. Think of this table as Account hasMany Shops hasMany Text. In the end, I want to build an object where I can access account.shops[0].text[0] .. the data is there to do it. Hibernate does this for us with the same set of data. But I can not with ease get there myself.

Comment: Does it need to be in Postgres or can it be SQL Server? You can do it in Postgres something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/cRaKpfDi

Comment: Neither, I think that was clear :) Whatever those DB's are capable of doing I would like to do on the backend instead. The output that was generated by your link was also incomplete unless the underlying data is wrong but something along those lines, but again, the goal is to do similarly but on the backend.